# arduino and esp8266 wifi module compiling issue

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266

I want to monitor the condition of the 2HP IM to using arduino uno and sensors and want to push the data to cloud using esp8266 in thingspeak. But I keep getting the error ""Softwere serial esp8266" redeclared as different kind of symbol " when compiled. please fix this problem
this is my coding:

```
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#define RX 10
#define TX 11
String AP = "wifi name";       // CHANGE ME

String PASS = "wifi password"; // CHANGE ME
String API = "api key";   // CHANGE ME
String HOST = "api.thingspeak.com";
String PORT = "80";
String field = "field1";
int countTrueCommand;
int countTimeCommand; 
boolean found = false; 
int valSensor = 1;
SoftwareSerial esp8266(RX,TX,false,256);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp8266.begin(115200);
  sendCommand("AT",5,"OK");
  sendCommand("AT+CWMODE=1",5,"OK");
  sendCommand("AT+CWJAP=\""+ AP +"\",\""+ PASS +"\"",20,"OK");
}

void loop() {
 valSensor = getSensorData();
 String getData = "GET /update?api_key="+ API +"&"+ field +"="+String(valSensor);
 sendCommand("AT+CIPMUX=1",5,"OK");
 sendCommand("AT+CIPSTART=0,\"TCP\",\""+ HOST +"\","+ PORT,15,"OK");
 sendCommand("AT+CIPSEND=0," +String(getData.length()+4),4,">");
 esp8266.println(getData);delay(1500);countTrueCommand++;
 sendCommand("AT+CIPCLOSE=0",5,"OK");
}

int getSensorData(){
  return random(1000); // Replace with 
}

void sendCommand(String command, int maxTime, char readReplay[]) {
  Serial.print(countTrueCommand);
  Serial.print(". at command => ");
  Serial.print(command);
  Serial.print(" ");
  while(countTimeCommand < (maxTime*1))
  {
    esp8266.println(command);//at+cipsend
    if(esp8266.find(readReplay))//ok
    {
      found = true;
      break;
    }

    countTimeCommand++;
  }

  if(found == true)
  {
    Serial.println("OYI");

    countTrueCommand++;
    countTimeCommand = 0;
  }

  if(found == false)
  {
    Serial.println("Fail");
    countTrueCommand = 0;
    countTimeCommand = 0;
  }

  found = false;
}
```

this is the error I am getting:

```
Arduino: 1.8.9 (Windows 8), Board: "Generic ESP8266 Module, 80 MHz, Flash, Disabled, ck, 26 MHz, 40MHz, DOUT (compatible), 512K (no SPIFFS), 2, v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\n12\n12.ino: In function 'void setup()':
n12:19:10: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
   esp8266.begin(115200);
          ^

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\n12\n12.ino: In function 'void loop()':
n12:30:9: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
  esp8266.println(getData);delay(1500);countTrueCommand++;
         ^

C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\n12\n12.ino: In function 'void sendCommand(String, int, char*)':
n12:43:12: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
     esp8266.println(command);//at+cipsend
            ^

n12:44:15: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
     if(esp8266.find(readReplay))//ok
               ^

exit status 1
expected primary-expression before '.' token

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: This is a little difficult to read as the code block seems to be broken up. I've edited it for you. FWIW, the SoftwareSerial constructor only takes three parameters (Not 4) according to the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerialConstructor)

Comment: The reason the code block was broken up was due to the indenting - please refer to [Markdown Editing](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for information about how to format posts.

Comment: Change the variable name to something else if there’s a collision?